# Extracting Substring from File Name

Tags: string, awk, substring, extract, cut

I have a list of files with the following file name format:

```
[some unknown amount of characters][_d][yyyymmdd][some unknown amount of characters]
```

I want to extract the substring that contains the date (`yyyymmdd`) which I know will always be proceeded by `"_d"`.  So basically I want to extract the first 8 characters after the `"_d"`.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: you need to make sure `_d` is not showing anywhere else before your date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `sed`:

```
$ echo "asdfasd_d20150616asdasd" | sed -r 's/^.*_d(.{8}).*$/\1/'
20150616
```

This gets a string and removes everything up to `_d`. Then, catches the following 8 characters and prints them back.

- `sed -r` is used to be able to catch groups with just `()` instead of `\(\)`.
- `^.*_d(.{8}).*$`

  - `^` beginning of line
  - `.*` any number of characters (even 0 of them)
  - `_d` literal _d you want to match
  - `(.{8})` since `.` matches any character, `.{8}` matches 8 characters. With `()` we catch them so that they can be reused later on.
  - `.*$` any number of characters up to the end of the line.
- `\1` print back the catched group.

Comment: Hey thanks! That worked perfectly!  Can you please explain to me the syntax of the expression?

Comment: @AlecH I just updated with some explanation about the command.